# How to 'personal_sign' with Mist browser

Tags: web3js, mist, metamask, web3-providers

I can use

```
web3.currentProvider.sendAsync({
  method: 'personal_sign',
  params: [msg, address],
  from: address,
}, (err, res) => {});
```

and Metamask will prompt the user to sign the given message.

In Mist, I get and error (`TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`) thrown from here:

```
EthereumProvider._addResponseCallback (<anonymous>:1097:42) 
at EthereumProvider.send (<anonymous>:1146:14)
```

Is this simply not possible with the Provider from Mist?
Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So appearently, this is not implemented in Mist yet, but they are [planning on doing so](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/3570) in the next release.

There is also a lot of discussion on how to exactly implement this feature in general.

There are EIPs discussing seperation of "data to be signed" and "presentation metadata"

([EIP712](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/pull/712) and [EIP719](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/719) mainly)

Can only recommend to read them to anyone interested :)